# iScroll4 and flowplayer working issue in android devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, flowplayer, iscroll4

I am using iScroll 4 and flowplayer to develop a project. In `iPad` and `iPhone` it is working properly but not in android devices for both tablets and mobiles. It seems flowplayer is loading and even the video is playing but cannot be viewed only hear the sound. Looks like something is overlaying the player and the video playing stops after a while. Also scrolling is working using iScroll but during scrolling there is some flickering effect and the content seems to be overlapped by something. Please help to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try programming it dynamically. Seems as though something in the xml is blocking it. Post the code if you want and ill take a look at it.